# Создание и редактирование моделей

Tags: c#, model, xsd

Как можно удобно создавать модели в среде .net core. К примеру классы можно описывать в XSD, но нет здравых утилит по переносу XSD в код под линуксом.
Возможно есть более удобные способы для создания моделей в .dot core под линксом